# How to binding nested class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

This is my class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public List<Sweet> sweetList { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        sweetList = new List<Sweet>();
    }
}

public class Sweet
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

In MainPage.xaml i set

```
DataContext = personList;
```

in XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding personList}" >
 <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding sweetList.Id}" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

How I can binding this class to XAML?
in the result i see only Name, but textBlock with sweetList.Id is empty
Please help

Comment: `sweetList` is of type `List<Sweet>` and `List<T>` does not have a property called `Id`. You are probably looking for something like `sweetList[0].Id`, although that's not ideal since there's no guarantee that `sweetList` contains at least 1 item, and you may want to see more than just the first item in the list. What are you trying to do here? There are probably better ways of accomplishing in it XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a collection in WPF, you need to use a container control, such as a `ListBox`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding sweetList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you also need to tell the Framework how to display your `Sweet` class, which is what the inner `ListBox.ItemTemplate` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an item template for each item in 'personList' but you're not doing the same for 'sweetList'.

As sweetList is a List, and not just a single Sweet, you either need to access the first one in the list by doing something like sweetList[0].Id, or probably you want to display each one from the list on the screen, in which case you need to do something similar as what you're doing with personList.

Comment: Need list in the form:
[link](http://postimg.org/image/493rtsybv/)
ofcourse Sweet class with only one property  is only example.
All person have list with candy. 
I must show All person, and all the goodies that they have.